# pyqt: copy paste whole row from QtTablewidget to another QTablewidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm discovering pyqt and I'm struggling to copy paste a whole row from one tablewidget to another. I've been able to copy paste single items but I don't know how to proceed for a whole row...

My code:

```
        for a in [self.tableWidget.selectedItems()[2]]:
            cloned_item = a.clone()
            self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(5)
            self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(0)
            self.tableWidget_2.setItem(0,0,cloned_item)
```

Comment: Just add an inner cycle that does `for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount())`.

Comment: Ok so there is no function that enables to copy a whole row ?

Comment: No. You could use `dropMimeData()` of the model, but I wouldn't suggest using it. Just cycle trough the columns, it's simpler and you have better control over what's happening.